# How to define values in code block uses data class with room?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I fetch data from API and I would like to reuse it in data class like this (ItemStateRoom is data with String, Int etc.):

```
@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class ItemRoom(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
    var type: String = "",
    var title: String = "",
    var template: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "state")
    @JsonAdapter(ItemStateAdapter::class)
    var state: ItemStateRoom?
 {
    var itemState: ItemStateRoom
        get() = state!!
        set(value) {
            state = value
        }
}
```

When I set state to null of course I have null, but program compiles well.
If it is like at the top error occurs:

```
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

I also tried to do like this:

```
    @Ignore
    @JsonAdapter(ItemStateAdapter::class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "state")
    var state: ItemStateRoom?,
```

Then I have errors:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
.ItemStateRoom state;

Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

EDIT1:
Description: I make realm to room migration, realmobjects are downloaded as well and they are not null, but some of objects(data classes) I have changed to Room i.e. `ItemStateRoom` or `ItemSubStatus`. For sure it is not null, I download it from backend in postman it gives value for sure.

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@Entity(tableName = "itemsubstatus")
data class ItemSubStatusRoom(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String? = null
)
```

TypeConverters:

```
class Converters {
    private val gson = GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

    @TypeConverter
    fun typeSubStatusToString(type: ItemSubStatusRoom?): String =
        gson.toJson(type)

    @TypeConverter
    fun typeItemSubStatusFromString(value: String): ItemSubStatusRoom? =
        gson.fromJson(value, ItemSubStatusRoom::class.java) as ItemSubStatusRoom?


}
```

My response data is simple:

```
class ItemsDataResponse (
        @SerializedName("items")
        val items: ArrayList<ItemRoom>,
        val total: Int
)
```

in my ItemData it is also simple

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)                                                                 
@Entity(tableName = "item")                                                                    
data class ItemRoom @JvmOverloads constructor(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
 [...]
  @ColumnInfo(name = "sub_status")
    var subStatus: ItemSubStatusRoom?,
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is saying there is no ***"public constructor"***, it is saying that it does not know how to construct the ItemRoom object that does not include the **state** field/member.

So with **state** `@Ignore'`d you would need to have a constructor that doesn't expect the **state** as a parameter.

- with a Data Class the definition within the parenthesises is the constructor as such.

e.g.

```
constructor(type: String, title: String, template: String): this(type = type, title = title, template = template, state = null)
```

- in which case Room would always construct an **ItemRoom** where state is null.

However, I suspect that the above is not what you want. Rather that you want the **state** to be saved in the database. As such, as it is not a type that can be stored directly and hence the need for a TypeConverter (actually 2)

- only String, integer (Int, Long, Byte, Boolean etc types), decimal (Float, Double etc types) or byte streams (ByteArray) can be stored directly

Then if you want the **state** field to be saved in the database, then you will need 2 **TypeConverter**s.

- One which will convert from the ItemStateRoom  to one of the types that can be stored (so it is passed an ItemStateRoom and returns one of the types that can be stored directly).
- The other will convert from the type stored to an ItemStateRoom object.

So assuming that you want to store the **state** you could have, something like :-

```
@TypeConverters(value = [Converters::class])
@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class ItemRoom(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
    var type: String = "",
    var title: String = "",
    var template: String = "",
    //@Ignore   /*<<<<< if used a constructor is needed that doesn't require the state, as the state is not available */
                /* if not used then state has to be converted to a type that room can store */
    @ColumnInfo(name = "state")
    @JsonAdapter(ItemStateAdapter::class)

    var state: ItemStateRoom?
)
{
    //constructor(type: String, title: String, template: String): this(type = type, title = title, template = template, state = null)
    var itemState: ItemStateRoom
        get() = state!!
        set(value) {
            state = value
        }
}

data class ItemStateRoom(
    /* made up ItemStateRoom */
    var roomNumber: Int,
    var roomType: String
)
class ItemStateAdapter() {
    /* whatever .... */
}

class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertItemStateRoomToJSONString(itemStateRoom: ItemStateRoom): String = Gson().toJson(itemStateRoom)
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromJSONStringToItemStateRoom(jsonString: String): ItemStateRoom = Gson().fromJson(jsonString,ItemStateRoom::class.java)
}
```

- note the commented out `@Ignore` and constructor (for if `@Ignore`'ing the **state** field).
- how you implement, if at all, the @JsonAdapter, would be as you have it.
- note the `@TypeConverters` (which you would omit if `@Ignore`ing the **state** field)

  - It might be preferable to include the `@TypeConverters` at the `@Database` level, where it has full scope. (see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverters)

**Example**

Here's an example of storing the **state** (ItemStateRoom) that uses the code above, with a pretty standard @Database annotated class and an @Dao annotated interface :-

```
@Dao
interface ItemRoomDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(itemRoom: ItemRoom): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item")
    fun getAllItems(): List<ItemRoom>
}
```

Two items are inserted and then extracted and written to the log using the following activity code :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: ItemRoomDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getItemRoomDao()

        dao.insert(ItemRoom(type = "Bedroom", template =  "The Template", title = "Bedroom1", state = ItemStateRoom(101,"King size - Shower - Bath - Kitchenette")))
        dao.insert(ItemRoom(type = "Bedroom", template =  "The Template", title = "Bedroom2", state = ItemStateRoom(102,"Queen size - Shower - Bath")))
        for(i in dao.getAllItems()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Item ID is ${i.id} Title is ${i.title} Room Number is ${i.state!!.roomNumber} Room Type is ${i.state!!.roomType}")
        }    
    }
}
```

The result in the log:-

```
D/DBINFO: Item ID is 1 Title is Bedroom1 Room Number is 101 Room Type is King size - Shower - Bath - Kitchenette
D/DBINFO: Item ID is 2 Title is Bedroom2 Room Number is 102 Room Type is Queen size - Shower - Bath
```

The database via **App Inspection** :-

[image]

- as can be seen the ItemStateRoom has been converted to (and from according to the output in the log) a JSON String.
- Ignore the weatherforecast table, that was from another answer that was used for providing this answer.

**Alternative Approach**

Instead of converting the ItemState to a JSON representation (which is unwieldly from a database perspective) consider the potential advantages of instead embedding the ItemState. The difference in this approach is that the fields of the ItemState are each saved as individual columns.

e.g.

```
@Entity(tableName = "item")
data class ItemRoom(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
    var type: String = "",
    var title: String = "",
    var template: String = "",
    //@Ignore   /*<<<<< if used a constructor is needed that doesn't require the state, as the state is not available */
                /* if not used then state has to be converted to a type that room can store */
    //@ColumnInfo(name = "state")
    //@JsonAdapter(ItemStateAdapter::class)
    //var state: ItemStateRoom?
    @Embedded
    var itemStateRoom: ItemStateRoom
)
{
    //constructor(type: String, title: String, template: String): this(type = type, title = title, template = template, state = null)
    /*
    var itemState: ItemStateRoom
        get() = state!!
        set(value) {
            state = value
        }
     */
}
```

Thus to update, at least from the database aspect, you are freed from trying to manipulate a representation of the data. You can update the actual data directly.

Using the above, with the example code (changed to use `itemState` instead of `state`) then the database looks like:-

[image]

You say

> But to reassign values dynamically I have to use @JsonAdapter.

The JsonAdapter is NOT going to magically update the data in the database, to update the data you will have to use a function in an interface (or an abstract class) that is annotated with @Dao which will either be annotated with @Update (convenience) or @Query (with appropriate UPDATE SQL).

Comment: Wow, Mike thank you for this really nice leture I;m on it!

Comment: Thanks, it works. But to reasign values dynamically I have to use @JsonAdapter. Do you know any other approachs?

Comment: @Vidar567 I have added an additional alternative approach. However, I suspect that you might be assuming that JSON has qualities it does not have and will automatically update the database when you say " But to reasign values dynamically I have to use @JsonAdapter".